# Using WebClient to access protected pages with Login

Tags: c#, session, cookies, webclient

I am trying to access page, which is protected by Login Form. I've checked around the topics in SO, and I've found this extension for the WebClient, which uses cookies:

```cs
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

With more help from the internet I came up with this bit of code:

```cs
using (var webClient = new CookieAwareWebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection
                {
                    {"UserName", userName},
                    {"Password", password}
                };

                webClient.UploadValues("https://judge.softuni.bg/Account/Login", "POST", collection);


                string result = webClient.DownloadString("https://judge.softuni.bg/Contests/Compete/Results/Simple/104");

            }
            catch (WebException webException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(webException.Status.ToString());
            }
        }
```

In the end in the "result" string I have the login page with Form action which will redirect me to the wanted page if I log in. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?